# What's causing "RuntimeError: No built-in server implementation installed." when I try a demo reactpy script in python?

Tags: python, reactjs

I hit `RuntimeError: No built-in server implementation installed.` when I try

```
python -c "import reactpy; reactpy.run(reactpy.sample.SampleApp)"
```

which is a getting started app mentioned [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2023/06/getting-started-reactpy.html). `python -m http.server` runs fine.
Full stacktrace is

```
python -c "import reactpy; reactpy.run(reactpy.sample.SampleApp)"


2023-06-11T02:37:17+0300 | WARNING | The `run()` function is only intended for testing during development! To run in production, consider selecting a supported backend and importing its associated `configure()` function from `reactpy.backend.<package>` where `<package>` is one of ['starlette', 'fastapi', 'sanic', 'tornado', 'flask']. For details refer to the docs on how to run each package.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reactpy/backend/default.py", line 59, in _default_implementation
    implementation = next(all_implementations())
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reactpy/backend/utils.py", line 37, in run
    app = implementation.create_development_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reactpy/backend/default.py", line 28, in create_development_app
    return _default_implementation().create_development_app()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/reactpy/backend/default.py", line 62, in _default_implementation
    raise RuntimeError("No built-in server implementation installed.")
```

Any ideas what might be the problem? I've not seen reference to this in a quick google search.

Comment: From the error message, it seems like you need to install one of `['starlette', 'fastapi', 'sanic', 'tornado', 'flask']`.

Comment: i've got starlette and flask installed - also that part of the msg is a warning not an error, and in any case seems to imply I  don't need any of those for testing

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pip install takes a parameter, something the guide I quoted didn't mention - instead of `pip3 install reactpy` what I needed was
`pip3 install "reactpy[starlette]"`.  Why this didn't work with the individually installed reactpy and starlette (or flask) combo, I don't know.